# How to programmatically draw flowchart in visio

Tags: java, swt, ole, visio

Using SWT OLE Automation in Java I am programmatically drawing a flowchart in visio by reading source code line by line.But my logic goes wrong whenever there is if-else condition and also in case of nested if situations.Is there any standard algorithm which I could follow while drawing the flowchart in Visio.Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Create Visio Flowcharts Programmatically](http://www.visguy.com/2006/09/13/create-visio-flowcharts-programmatically/) by Chris Roth.